# Change AppBar title padding

Tags: flutter, dart

Due to unavailability of modifying app bar `leading` property width I'm forced to create my own leading trailing property by using AppBar `title` property. However I've noticed that title has some default horizontal padding there.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Container(
      height: 36,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: 80, child: Text('Cancel')),
          Text('Profile'),
          Container(width: 80, child: Text('Done'))
        ],
      ),
    ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Is there any way to make it smaller?

Comment: Did you check `titleSpacing` property of the `AppBar`?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta.. I didn't but I've just tried that and that is what I was looking for.. Thanks.. Please feel free to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [titleSpacing](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/titleSpacing.html) property of the AppBar to control the horizontal spacing for the title.

For example following snippet will remove all the leading spacing from title-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        title: const Text('AppBar Demo'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the home page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use action[] inside the appbar instead of using Row.

```
  appBar: new AppBar(
      //title: new Text(Strings.app_name),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: (){

          },
            child: new Text('Cancel'),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: 
          new RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
            
          },child: new Text('done'),)
        ),
      ],
      //centerTitle:true,
    ),
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question **Due to unavailability of modifying width of app bar leading property** I can not use leading and trailing therefore I have to use title.. The question is already answered in the comment btw

Comment: @delmin,i have edited the code.put title also if you want it.

Comment: I need title.. I also need leading and trailing but if your leading widget is for example a text and the text is too long then it will end up in multiline. Therefore I have to use title

Answer (score 1):

Please use titleSpacing: 0.0

```
appBar: AppBar(
    titleSpacing: 0.0,
    title: Text('AppBar Example'),
  ),
```